# How to fit image size to screen with cv2.Imshow

Tags: python, resize, opencv, imshow

first of all
I am sorry for posting questions using a translator because I am not good at English.

I am making a program in Python that shows images that have passed ObjectDetection in sequence.

As images of different sizes are displayed one after another, there is a lot of distortion in the image size.

So, how do I output the images so that they are resized and continuously converted on the same output screen so that they are not distorted?

Below is the code I am using now.

```
def DetectImage(_PATH_TO_IMAGE, _IMAGE_NAME, _sess, _category_index):
    image = cv2.imread(_PATH_TO_IMAGE)
    image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_rgb, axis=0)    
    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = _sess.run(
        [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
        feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})
    
    # Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=5,
        min_score_thresh=0.60)
    
    cv2.namedWindow('ObjectDetection_Checker', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.resizeWindow('ObjectDetection_Checker', 1280, 720)
    
    cv2.imshow('ObjectDetection_Checker', image)    
    # All the results have been drawn on image. Now display the image.
    cv2.imwrite('images/CheckedImages/' + _IMAGE_NAME + '_Checked.jpg', image)      
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: If you remove the line `cv2.resizeWindow`, each image will be displayed in a window according to the image size. Also if you want to show each image for 1 second, instead of `time.sleep(1)` set `cv2.waitKey(1000)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I want to display the image in a frame as long as the size does not change with the image. So, I want to resize the image to fit the screen without distortion (with the image proportion as it is, enlarge or reduce it). 
But the last cv.waitKey(1000) was definitely helpful. Thank you.

Comment: OK, but to which size do you want to resize the images? To have 720 Pixels on the short side or 1280 Pixels on the longer side or something else?

Comment: sorry my answer was late. I want a size of 1280X720 and I want a new ratio. I made the following example images.  Thanks to reply :) https://blogfiles.pstatic.net/MjAyMDExMjNfMTkx/MDAxNjA2MDk0OTE0OTIz.b8e7jZH7P0Esufs2eckghvXiTVE4feC3SFy4E_iAWdIg.Na4f72SyN8H_1KMiKxI0wSWiprkSW-e2Ej1DBKK2AxAg.PNG.hisny/testImage_2.png

Comment: Yes but if you apply a new ratio to an image it will get "distorted" as you call it right?

Comment: Yes, it is. What I called'distortion' is that not all images have the same size ratio, so if I change it to a certain size, it lengthens up or stretches sideways. I called that as 'distortion'.

Comment: Yes, what do you want to do if a image has not the ratio to fit into 1280x720? Stretch it anyways?

Comment: Yes, I want the images to be enlarged to fit the size while maintaining a certain ratio. If the images are of different ratio, I want the background to merge black so that all images can be viewed in a window of the same size.
It seems that the example image was not well seen, so we provide the following example image. Last time https://postfiles.pstatic.net/MjAyMDExMjVfMTkz/MDAxNjA2MjY3MDcxMDI2.DCVuHgP1YKKY1McI3xHb2uBKUKwRTylXPNSQmVKotVMg.HQJXXAAK3C2ut_7EZaN-vv6Cuyd_WsZsM5ziyjqRq_Ag.PNG.hisny/01_image.png?type=w580

Comment: https://postfiles.pstatic.net/MjAyMDExMjVfMTQ1/MDAxNjA2MjY3MDc0NDMz.d5Qe9ITre2p0WVbxh6S2z0YCoNbjV1dtjCtpA_dglxkg.wuFQiG3a7K1lDGkqqgatU8BGFubmya6Nyug5oIT1W_cg.PNG.hisny/02_image.png?type=w580

Answer (score 1):

since differnet screens have different sizes, you can get the size of the screen using `ctypes`;

```
import ctypes
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
```

and then just resize the image to the variable `screensize`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to get the screen size successfully. But, as I said above, can I fix the screen size and only modify the size of the image inside? If I want to avoid image size distortion and want to fix the size of the showing window, I want to keep the window showing the image as it is, and hide the image where it is not visible, or display it in black.

Comment: most modules DO make it look non-resized, the only one i have seen does not is HTML, so it just may look clear

Comment: sorry my answer was late. Let me refer to the advice. Thanks for the answer. :)